# How to get the parent theme programmatically

Tags: android, android-theme

Let's say I have the following custom theme declared in `themes.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.Custom.Light" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.Light.ActionBar.TabView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.Light.ActionBar.TabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/ab_item_text</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Custom.Light.Widget.ActionBar.Menu</item>
</style>
```

From the application context, we are able to get the `Theme` class currently applied using

```
Theme myTheme = appContext.getTheme();
```

and also, we are able to get the theme's resource id using:

```
int themeResId = appContext.getApplicationInfo().theme;
```

---

### What I want

From my code, I would like to check **programmatically** which is the parent theme of the theme I'm using in order to differentiate between `Sherlock`, `Sherlock.Light` & `Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`.

In the example above, I would like to know that I am using the Light variation of the Sherlock theme.

**Note:** *You may wonder why I need to check the parent if I declared it in the xml. Reason is that I'm in a particular situation in which I actually won't know, but this goes beyond the scope of this question.*

Answer (score 0):

```
 Theme myTheme = appContext.getTheme();
```

You can get its parent class using

```
 Theme myThemeParent = appContext.getTheme().getClass().getSuperclass();
```

and compare it with **Sherlock**.getclass() to verify if it is the parent. Likewise for other comparisons.